# Zoom Screen Share not working in 22.04 app

Tags: 22.04

Currently able to share using the google chrome Zoom, however this is simply less convenient than the application itself.

I have used the following command:

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

and confirmed my system is using wayland.

Using this following command:

WaylandEnable=false

I turned wayland off. However, in doing so, when I rebooted my PC, everything on screen is a horrible bright yellow tint, making it basically unusable, and so I have to re-enable wayland.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: are you perhaps using a TV instead of a monitor? See [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/v551ix/why_would_xorg_make_my_tv_look_yellow/) for info about that